# How to make drop down menu enable with only one value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down menu that retrieved ID from database and four labels. From the user id, the labels will display data that belongs to the ID. In my case, the ID only has 1 value which it makes the auto post back not refresh the page. Is there any ways to make the labels show the data?

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Id" DataValueField="Id" 
                Height="16px" Width="145px" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Connection %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [Id] FROM [Rsvp] WHERE (([Model] = @Model) AND ([Username] = @Username))">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="Model" 
                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList3" Name="Username" 
                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert a new Item at 0, at the top:

```
DropDownList5.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("Select an option","-"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `AppendDataBoundItems` property to `true` on the dropdown list and the items from the data source will appear after any ListItems you add in the markup e.g.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Id" DataValueField="Id" 
            Height="16px" Width="145px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="-" Text="Select an option" Selected="True"/>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But my drop down list is only accept int. When I applied your code, error : Input string was not in correct format